# How to creating a MapFile with Spark and access it?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, mapr

I am trying to create a MapFile from a Spark RDD, but can't find enough information. Here are my steps so far:

I started with,

`rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(....MapFileOutputFormat.class)`

which threw an Exception as the `MapFiles` must be sorted.
So I modified to:

`rdd.sortByKey().saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(....MapFileOutputFormat.class)`

which worked fine and my MapFile was created. So the next step was  accessing the file. Using the directory name where `parts` were created failed saying that it cannot find the `data` file. Back to Google, I found that in order to access the `MapFile` parts I needed to use:

```
Object ret = new Object();//My actual WritableComparable impl
Reader[] readers = MapFileOutputFormat.getReaders(new Path(file), new Configuration());
Partitioner<K,V> p = new HashPartitioner<>();
Writable e = MapFileOutputFormat.getEntry(readers, p key, ret);
```

Naively, I ignored the `HashPartioner` bit and expected that this would find my entry, but no luck. So my next step was to loop over the readers and do a `get(..)`. This solution did work, but it was extremely slow as the files were created by 128 tasks resulting in 128 `part` files.

So I investigated the importance of `HashPartitioner` and found that internally it uses it to identify which reader to use, but it seems that Spark is not using the same partitioning logic. So I modified to:

`rdd.partitionBy(new org.apache.spark.HashPartitioner(128)).sortByKey().saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(....MapFileOutputFormat.class)`

But again the 2 `HashPartioner` did not match. So the questions part...

- Is there a way to combine the `MapFiles` efficiently (as this would ignore the paritioning logic)?
- `MapFileOutputFormat.getReaders(new Path(file), new
  Configuration());` is very slow. Can I identify the reader more
  efficiently?
- I am using MapR-FS as the underlying DFS. Will this be using the same `HashParitioner` implementation?
- Is there a way to avoid repartitioning, or should the data be sorted over the whole file? (In contrast to being sorted within the partition)
- I am also getting an exception `_SUCCESS/data does not exist`. Do I need to manually delete this file?

Any links about this would be greatly appreciated.

PS. If entries are sorted, then how is it possible to use the  `HashPartitioner` to locate the correct `Reader`? This would imply that data `parts` are `Hash Partitioned` and then Sorted by key. So I also tried `rdd.repartiotionAndSortWithinPartitions(new HashPartitioner(280))`, but again without any luck.

Comment: Hey, did you happen to find a solution for this case?

Comment: Not really. I moved to using Avro & Parquet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging into the issue, I found that the Spark HashPartitioner and Hadoop HashPartitioner have different logic.

So the "brute force" solution I tried and works is the following.

Save the MapFile using `rdd.repartitionAndSortWithinPArtitions(new
 org.apache.aprk.HashPartitioner(num_of_parititions)).saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(....MapFileOutputFormat.class);`

Lookup using:

- Reader[] readers = MapFileOutputFormat.getReaders(new Path(file),new Configuration());
- org.apache.aprk.HashPartitioner p = new org.apache.aprk.HashPartitioner(readers.length);
- readers[p.getPartition(key)].get(key,val);

This is "dirty" as the MapFile access is now bound to the Spark partitioner rather than the intuitive Hadoop HashPartitioner. I could implement a Spark partitioner that uses Hadoop `HashPartitioner` to improve on though.

This also does not address the problem with slow access to the relatively large number of reducers. I could make this even 'dirtier' by generating the file part number from the partitioner but I am looking for a clean solution, so please post if there is a better approach to this problem.